# Edit Previously commit SVN message

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Recently,  I have committed some code into Tortoise SVN by providing some commit message like **Added two java files test.java and test1.java**. After committing the code, I realized that I wrote a wrong commit message and correct one should be **Update two java files test.java and test1.java**. Is there a way to change the commit message?

Comment: While possible, generally no. Also, it is easy to see when you have added verses updated files, so your commit message is redundant. Why not have a comment for what the files do or what you changed?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, but the administrator of your Subversion repository must have it enabled - I believe it is disabled by default. If it's already enabled, from TortoiseSVN -> Show Log, simply right click your revision in the log and choose "edit log message". If it is not enabled, this operation will fail.

This functionality relies on the [pre-revprop-change repository hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html). Quoted from the SVN 1.7 manual:

> The pre-revprop-change hook is run immediately prior to the
>   modification of a revision property when performed outside the scope
>   of a normal commit. Unlike the other hooks, the default state of this
>   one is to deny the proposed action. The hook must actually exist and
>   return a zero exit value before a revision property modification can
>   happen.

In your repository's "hooks" directory (on the Subversion server), a platform-appropriate script must be present and, as stated above, return a zero exit value. For instance, you may want to allow the user who made a commit to edit their commit log message later.

Here's an [example pre-revprop-change batch script for Windows on someone's blog](http://ayria.livejournal.com/33438.html). I did not write this script, but we've used this in our environment so I can confirm it works for me.